# SQL Outer Join -- Join requires 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, outer-join

I'm using SQL Server query designer to try and form an outer query that will return the full name and address of each insured with home policies and those without policies. My create statements are the following:

```
    CREATE TABLE Address (
    AddressID integer NOT NULL,
    HouseNumber Integer NOT NULL,
    Street varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    CityCounty varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    StateAbb char(2),
    CountryAbb char(2) NOT NULL,
    Zip char(5) NOT NULL,
    LastUpdatedBy varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    LastUpdated date NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Address PRIMARY KEY (AddressID));

    CREATE TABLE Insured(
    InsuredID integer NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    MI char(1),
    DateOfBirth date NOT NULL,
    CreditScore integer NOT NULL,
    AddressID integer NOT NULL,
    DriversLicenseNumber varchar(35), 
    LastUpdatedBy varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    LastUpdated date NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Insured PRIMARY KEY (InsuredID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_InsuredAddress FOREIGN KEY (AddressID) references  Address);

    CREATE TABLE Policy(
    PolicyID integer NOT NULL,
    EffectiveDate date NOT NULL,
    TerminationDate date NOT NULL,
    Amount Numeric (8,2) NOT NULL,
    PolicyYear integer NOT NULL,
    PolicyType char(1) NOT NULL,
    InsuredID integer NOT NULL,
    AddressID integer NOT NULL,
    LastUpdatedBy varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    LastUpdated date NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Policy PRIMARY KEY (PolicyID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_PolicyAddress FOREIGN KEY (AddressID) references Address,
    CONSTRAINT FK_PolicyInsured FOREIGN KEY (InsuredID) references Insured);

    CREATE TABLE Home(
    PolicyID integer NOT NULL,
    ExteriorType varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Alarm char(3) NOT NULL,
    DistanceToFireStation integer NOT NULL,
    LastUpdatedBy varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    LastUpdated date NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Home PRIMARY KEY (PolicyID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_HomePolicy FOREIGN KEY (PolicyID) references Policy);

    CREATE TABLE Auto(
    PolicyID integer NOT NULL,
    VinNumber varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Make varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    Model varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    MilesPerYear integer NOT NULL,
    LastUpdatedBy varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    LastUpdated date NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Auto PRIMARY KEY (PolicyID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_AutoPolicy FOREIGN KEY (PolicyID) references Policy);
```

I believe that the query requires tables address, insured, policy and an outer right or left join but I cant get SQL server to recognize this as it keeps forming an inner join and cross join. What do I need for a query that returns insureds with home policies and their addresses and insureds with no policy and their addresses?

What I've tried so far:

```
SELECT Insured.InsuredID, Insured.FirstName, 
       Insured.LastName, Address.HouseNumber, 
       Policy.PolicyID 
FROM Address RIGHT JOIN Policy 
ON Address.AddressID = Policy.AddressID 
RIGHT JOIN Insured ON Policy.AddressID = Insured.AddressID 
ORDER BY Insured.InsuredID
```

This is the most recent query that returns what I need for insureds with a home policy but for the insureds without a policy I get nulls in the address.

```
SELECT i.InsuredID, i.FirstName, i.MI, i.LastName,            
a.HouseNumber, a.Street, a.CityCounty, a.StateAbb, a.CountryAbb, a.Zip 
FROM INSURED i 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Policy WHERE PolicyType = 'H') HomePolicy on    
i.InsuredID = HomePolicy.InsuredID 
LEFT JOIN Address a on HomePolicy.AddressID = a.AddressID;
```

Comment: Show us your work.

Comment: The closest I've gotten:  SELECT Insured.InsuredID, Insured.FirstName, Insured.LastName, Address.HouseNumber, Policy.PolicyID

FROM Address

RIGHT JOIN Policy ON Address.AddressID = Policy.AddressID
RIGHT JOIN Insured ON Policy.AddressID = Insured.AddressID

ORDER BY Insured.InsuredID;

Comment: I will add to your original question - please do that in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this query:

```
SELECT i.InsuredID,
i.FirstName,
i.LastName,
a.HouseNumber,
p.PolicyID
FROM insured i
LEFT JOIN policy p ON i.AddressID = p.AddressID AND p.PolicyType = 'H'
LEFT JOIN address a ON i.AddressID = a.AddressID
ORDER BY i.InsuredID;
```

I think the joins were in the wrong order. Does this give you what you need?
Update: Joining the Insured table to the Address table will show you addresses regardless of if they have a policy or not.

Comment: I changed what you posted a little and its returning insureds with a home policy but for the insureds with no policy their address is returned as null so I'm definitely getting closer.

Comment: Ah, got it. I've changed the join a bit, is this now OK?

Comment: That's definitely even closer. The only problem now is that the query is returning all insureds (home policy, auto policy, no policy) not just insureds with a home policy and insureds without a policy.

Comment: I've updated the query to add the PolicyType = 'H' to the JOIN. I think this will give you what you need. Having a criteria in the JOIN clause means it is evaluated before the JOIN occurs, but in the WHERE clause it is evaluated after the JOIN occurs, so I think it's the right way around. Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Database design seem good.I think we have minor doubts regarding "PolicyType" column. what value it hold and what is the purpose of this column.

Say `PolicyType='H'` it mean that it is home policy . Or other way of finding same query is to check if that `policyid` exists in `home` table.

Is this correct ?

Main query,

> What do I need for a query that returns insureds with home policies
>   and their addresses and insureds with no policy and their addresses?

Check this script,

```
--insureds with home policies and their addresses 
select i.InsuredID,
i.FirstName,
i.LastName
A.HouseNumber
,1 INDICATE
from Insured i
INNER JOIN policy p ON i.InsuredID = p.InsuredID 
INNER JOIN [Address] A ON A.ADDRESSID=I.ADDRESSID
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT PolicyID FROM Home H WHERE h.PolicyID=P.PolicyID)
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT PolicyID FROM [Auto] a WHERE A.PolicyID=P.PolicyID)

UNION ALL
--insureds with no policy and their addresses
select i.InsuredID,
i.FirstName,
i.LastName
,A.HouseNumber
,0 INDICATE
from Insured i
INNER JOIN [Address] A ON A.ADDRESSID=I.ADDRESSID
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT InsuredID FROM   policy p WHERE i.InsuredID = p.InsuredID )
```

I have use "EXISTS clause" because that table column is not require in your output.